# Constructing an expression from a type scheme

Tags: types, scheme, expression

So I am asked to find a expression for the following type:

```
(int -> ((int -> (bool -> int)) -> (bool -> int)))
```

So I have constructed the following code to produce (bool -> int) However it's the combination bugging me:

```
(%which (T)
        (%typing '(lambda (f)
                    (lambda (x)
                      (succ (f (not x)))))
                 T))
```

Can anyone tell me any good rules or methods? :)

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I think it becomes a bit more obvious when you remove redundant parentheses from the type (like a non-schemer would write it):

```
int -> (int -> bool -> int) -> bool -> int
```

So you are supposed to write a function that is given three arguments and returns an `int`. That is, a solution must be expressible in the form:

```
lambda n. lambda f. lambda b. ____
```

But how do you fill in the hole? Well, looking at what types you get from the parameters, it is easy to see that you can just plug them together by applying `f` to `n` and `b`, yielding an `int`. So:

```
lambda n. lambda f. lambda b. f n b
```

That's one solution. But looking at the term carefully one notices that the innermost lambda can actually be eta-reduced, giving an even simpler term:

```
lambda n. lambda f. f n
```

But in fact, the question is a bit degenerate, because returning an int is always trivial. So the simplest solution probably is:

```
lambda n. lambda f. lambda b. 0
```

The general scheme to arrive at a solution often is by simple induction on the type structure: if you need a function, then write down a lambda and proceed recursively with the body. If you need a tuple, then write down a tuple and proceed recursively with its components. If you need a primitive type, well you can just pick a constant. If you need something you don't have (usually in the polymorphic case), look for some of the function parameters in scope that would give you such a thing. If that parameter is itself a function, try to recursively construct a suitable argument.

Comment: If I enter lambda n lambda f and lambda b followed by a 0 I get (int*int) - I want (int --> int) - I might need to add an extra lambda as you suggested but in the mean time avoid (*)

Comment: @Fedtekansler, not sure I follow. Where is the pair coming from? What was the exact term you entered?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of tools out there to derive implementations from types (via the Curry/Howard correspondance). An example is [Djinn](http://hackage.haskell.org/cgi-bin/hackage-scripts/package/djinn). There's [an introduction](http://www.polyomino.f2s.com/david/haskell/programsfromproofs.html), showing how in general to generate terms from types.

You might be able to learn more about Curry-Howard, and port the type-to-code tools to Scheme?

Comment: I have a similar explanation on the lecture notes from the University, however they seem unclear and without code as an example.

Answer (score 0):

For the specifics of your question (rather than general techniques), here's how I might go about it:

`(int -> ((int -> (bool -> int)) -> (bool -> int)))` can be simplified to `(A -> ((A -> B) -> B))` where `A = int` and `B = (bool -> int)`. This simplified version is easy to construct:

```
(lambda (a)
  (lambda (f)
    (f a)))
```

It's easy to see why this works: `a` has type `A`, and `f` has type `(A -> B)`, so calling `(f a)` will result in `B`. To put concrete types to those variables, `a` has type `int`, `f` has type `(int -> (bool -> int))`, and the result is, of course, `(bool -> int)`.

So, now you need to find a suitable function that has type `(int -> (bool -> int))` to slot into the `f` parameter. This is pretty simple to make an example of:

```
(lambda (n)
  (lambda (negate?)
    ((if negate? - +) n)))
```

And here's how you might use those functions:

```
> (define (foo a)
    (lambda (f)
      (f a)))
> (define (bar n)
    (lambda (negate?)
      ((if negate? - +) n)))
> (define baz ((foo 42) bar))
> (baz #t)
-42
> (baz #f)
42
```

Comment: Hmm, this question is about schelog and simple-types... What your answer provides is regular scheme code. I search knowledge in the form I described with the (%which (%typing)) structure

Comment: This would be a _great_ time to edit your question to include words and tags like schelog and simple-types. We aren't mind-readers here!

Comment: I can't create new tags, since I am new... So adding schelog and simple-types wasn't an option.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I searched for:

(lambda (i)
    (lambda (f)
      (lambda (b)
        (succ ((f (succ i)) (not b))))))

Which can be confirmed by:
 (%which (T)
        (%typing
          '(lambda (i)
             (lambda (f)
               (lambda (b)
                 (succ ((f (succ i)) (not b))))))
          T))

Succ makes sure it's an integer and not --> bool.